# Is there a way to use str_detect with group_by in R?

Tags: r, string, variables, group-by

I want to create a group of variables that all contain "AA" in the variable name, so that I can create summary statistics for the new group. I am not sure how to combine the str_detect and group_by function.

Comment: welcome! Please try to give a minimal working example, see [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(across(contains("AA")))
```

Please provide a reproducible example or sample data if you need more guidance.